# Is it possible to block clicks on my domain's links when used on another website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-headers, http-referer, web-application-firewall

Is it possible to block traffic (to a 401 page, for example) if a user clicks on a URL from my domain that's used to 301 redirect to another domain? All the URLs have the same structure: "www.mywebsite.com/go/*"

I'm using the ThirstyAffiliate plugin on WordPress to manage a large number of external links. My content is being scraped and republished by other websites, however, including my ThirstyAffiliate links. I'm thus getting clicks on those links from suspicious sources and I would like to block them.

Ideally, I would like to block these clicks with AWS WAF, since that's the solution we're using with CloudFront to serve our content. I can also do it at the server-level if needed though.

I'm guessing using the Referer header would be a good place to start, but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: `Referer` is easily faked and is not sufficient to protect confidential data. However, it might be sufficient for your particular use-case. See: [Bucket policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-HTTP-HTTPS)

Comment: Thanks for the comment John!

This isn't a situation that requires a particular level of security. It's just to prevent spam abuse really. 

I'm not sure to see how the S3 bucket policies you shared can help, though. Can you please clarify? The website's content is served through CloudFront, but it's not on AWS S3.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I didn't realise that  you were serving your own content through CloudFront rather than S3. (I see it now). Perhaps this can help: [How to Prevent Hotlinking by Using AWS WAF, Amazon CloudFront, and Referer Checking | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prevent-hotlinking-by-using-aws-waf-amazon-cloudfront-and-referer-checking/)

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up John! I'm serving my own content through CloudFront indeed. I used the guide you shared to set up AWS WAF rules for image hotlinking, but I see now that I might also be able to use the second approach described in that guide by filtering by path. I'll give that a try.